# Unable to install Recharts using npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, recharts

npm install recharts using npm I get the following in my console

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE                                         
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree            
npm ERR!                                                       
npm ERR! While resolving: project@0.1.0                        
npm ERR! Found: react@18.0.0                                   
npm ERR! node_modules/react                                    
npm ERR!   react@"^18.0.0" from the root project               
npm ERR!                                                       
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:                         
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.0.0 || ^17.0.0" from recharts@2.1.9   
npm ERR! node_modules/recharts                                 
npm ERR!   recharts@"*" from the root project                  
npm ERR!                                                       
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry        
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps      
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) depend
ency resolution.                                               
npm ERR!                                                       
npm ERR! See \npm-cache\eresolve-r
eport.txt for a full report.                                   
                                                               
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:           
npm ERR!     \npm-cache\_logs\2022
-04-21T22_49_43_368Z-debug.log
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. The problem is because you're using React 18 and the library require react 16 or 17

Answer (score 1):

try running `npm install recharts --force` or `npm install recharts --legacy-peer-deps`
if that doesnt work, remove node modules folder and install deps again
if it still doesnt work, then you might have to downgrade your react version to 16 or 17